# How to return json string of arrays using rapidjson

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I have a json file which looks like this

```
{
    "ActivityId":"CB8FA1DA-DCB4-40B3-9D12-2786BD89B4D4",
    "AdditionalParams":{
        
    }, 

    "Extensions":[
        {
            "Id":"1234",
            "IsEnabled":false,
            "Name":"Name1"
        },
        {
            "Id":"4567",
            "IsEnabled":false,
            "Name":"Name2"
        },
        {
            "Id":"8910",
            "IsEnabled":true,
            "Name":"Name3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I see a lot of code online which tries to get the IsEnabled,Name fields(as an example). However, I am trying to use [rapidjson](https://rapidjson.org/) to print out the array of extensions as is.

Here is the code that I have tried

```
 Document document;
    document.Parse(json);
   if (document.HasMember(L"Extensions")) {     
        eventPayload = document[L"Extensions"].GetString();
    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting in `eventPayload`? a string representation of the json fragment? That's not what `GetString` does.

Comment: I am expecting to print out the entire Extensions array in eventPayload. While I understand what getstring does- here, I want to display the entire array as is, but don't see any inbuilt function for that

Answer (score 1):

`document[L"Extensions"]` is not a string, it's an array, so you will have to first `getArray`, then iterate through it with a `JSONIterator` and then get the value of `IsEnabled`.

Also, you don't have to use `L""`, since they are normal strings and not wide strings.